# How do I use a credential file for CIFS in /etc/fstab?

Tags: fstab, cifs

I’m having a problem with fstab on Server 18.04. I’m trying to mount a number of Windows Server network shares. If I put the username and password into each line of fstab and do `sudo mount -a`, it works fine. However, when I try to use a “credentials” file, it all goes pear-shaped.

So this:

```
//server/share /mount/point cifs ro,auto,user=user,password=password 0 0
```

…works fine.

However, if I try this:

```
//server/share /mount/point cifs ro,auto,credentials=/etc/.smbcredentials 0 0
```

…with `.smbcredentials` containing the following:

```
user=username  
password=password  
domain=domain
```

…this does not work. `sudo mount -a -v` outputs the following:

```
/ : ignored  
/boot/efi : already mounted  
none : ignored  
domain=mydomain  
,prefixpath=Projects/XYZ,pass=********.168.1.10,unc=\server\share,user=username  
mount error(13): Permission denied  
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

`168.1.10` is the partial IP address of the server on which the shares that I want to mount are located. It appears that the password is being concatenated onto the IP of the server.

So, what am I doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The credentials file is supposed to use `username=username` rather than `user=..` though I can't see how that would cause this problem. Was that just a typo in the post?

Comment: Hi, I've seen examples that use either user or username. I'm not sure if you can use either or only one or the other.  Paul

Comment: Yeah, I've just tried it on a 14.04 server and you're correct. Either of them work. I'm afraid I don't have anything else to offer, hopefully someone more knowledgeable will be along to help.

Comment: Long shot, but does the file `/etc/.smbcredentials` have the proper permissions and owner/group? Even though you are trying to mount as `sudo`.

Comment: A related post on Unix SE: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124342/mount-error-13-permission-denied It mentions debugging the issue in dmesg and syslog. It might be due to the default `sec` being selected when using credentials.

Comment: @Dan That's a good point. FWIW I currently use `sec=ntlmv2`.

Comment: Does your credentials file have the correct (Unix-style) line terminations? or does it use Windows style CRLF?

Comment: Hi, .smbcredentials is owned by root and is rw for root only.

Comment: fstab and .smbcredentials I edited/created in Ubuntu with nano.

Answer (score 11):

My working credentials file is located in my ~ folder and looks like this

```
username=[username]
password=[password]
```

Its permissions are `-rw-------` and it is owned by my user.

The corresponding fstab line is

```
//[URL]/[sharename] /media/[mountpoint] cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/home/[username]/.sharelogin,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=[username],gid=[username],nofail 0 0
```

I don't use "domain" but that doesn't mean that you don't need it.

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggested version - still can't get it to work with a credentials file. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Are you supplying the correct credentials? It works fine for me.

Comment: This first gives an error `mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 14 -- ignored` and then after fixing what I think is `.sharelogin` to `,sharelogin` it gives `bad option uid="admin"`. Finally, you don't make any distinction between the local user login and the remote user login when filling in the credentials file so I'm not sure which one to use.

Comment: @anon58192932 It's `/home/[username]/.sharelogin` and it works great for me.  You need to supply credentials for the system you are trying to access, not the one you already have access to. If you have a new question, it's better to post it as such.  However, if you comment with the exact syntax of your `fstab` line, I'll be glad to take a look at it.

Comment: This answer assumes that `username` is the same on local and remote.
At the very least, in the ~/.sharelogin file content, that `username` must be the remote username. Yet in the `fstab` line the `/home/[username]/.sharelogin` must be the local username. Thus we have no idea if `uid=[username]` is referring to the local user or the remote user and since the field is `uid` if we can pass a numeric value.

Comment: I have a follow-up question to this, how would the fstab line be written if you have multiple shares? I have like 10-15 SMB shares setup on one device, and I obviously don't want to have to list that many lines in the fstab.

Comment: @RaleighL. you make a mount for each folder you want in /mnt/ - if you want one, share the root; or, group accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue, check for errors with:

```
tail -f /var/log/kern.log
```

-- > kernel: [ 7917.935203] CIFS VFS: No username specified

```
$ sudo apt install cifs-utils
```

Fixed it for me..

Comment: Had a similer error in `dmesg` but fix was the same. `Status code returned 0xc000006d STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE`

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble mounting my QNAP NAS Samba share on Ubuntu 18.04 with a credentials file. Here's what worked for me after trying on and off for months.

1. Find your Ubuntu username and create an identically named user with the password of your choice on your QNAP nas with the appropriate R/W permissions to your shared folder. So my username for Ubuntu is `username` so I created a user on QNAP called `username` and generated a random password with LastPass.
2. Create a file to hold the Samba login credentials: `nano ~/.samba_credentials`
3. Add the following lines:

```
username=your_shared_linx_and_qnap_username
password=the_qnap_user_password_you_chose
domain=WORKGROUP
```

Here's how mine looks:

```
username=username
password=last_pass_password
domain=WORKGROUP
```

The domain option might be optional but the default Windows 10 workgroup is `WORKGROUP` so this should work as long as you didn't change it. And if you did change it you probably know what a workgroup is and what value you changed it to.

4. Create the folder where your share will mount locally. `mkdir /media/username/storage`
5. Then edit your `/etc/fstab` file to auto-mount the QNAP Samba share via CIFS:
6. `//nas1da09d.local/files /media/username/storage cifs credentials=/home/username/.samba_credentials,uid=username,noperm,rw 0 0`

Answer (score -1):

When mounting several smb drives with same credentials you have to create one credential file per mount.
In other words, you can not use one credential file for several mounts.

Create a new file for each mount

```
sudo nano /etc/.smbcredentials1
sudo nano /etc/.smbcredentials2
sudo nano /etc/.smbcredentials3
```

add your credentials to each file

```
username=username
password=password
domain=WORKGROUP
```

then chmod the files for protection

```
sudo chmod 0600 .smbcredentials1 .smbcredentials2 .smbcredentials3
```

then use each file as credantials for each mount
sudo nano /etc/fstab

```
//server/share /mount/point cifs ro,auto,credentials=/etc/.smbcredentials1 0 0
//server/share /mount/point cifs ro,auto,credentials=/etc/.smbcredentials2 0 0
//server/share /mount/point cifs ro,auto,credentials=/etc/.smbcredentials3 0 0
```

then mount

```
sudo mount -a -v
```

this will probably solve your issue.

Comment: There is no reason to create a different credential file for each mount.  I use one file for three differnet mounts and it works perfectly well.

Comment: Yeah, this is wrong. I use the same file for 3 different mounts.